# A question regarding lines between points.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

On pg.13 of Lang's "Second Course in Calculus", the following is asserted:

> Let $P=(2,1)$ and $A=(-1,5)$. Then the parametric equation of the line through $P$ and in the direction of $A$ gives us $x=2-t, y=1+5t$.

Shouldn't the equations be $x=2+3t, =1-4t$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no.

What they mean, here, is that the line passes through the *point* $P$, and is in the direction of the *vector* from $(0,0)$ to $A$. That was very poorly phrased, though, and they are equivocating on how to treat an ordered pair.

Comment: Ah. Parallel to $A$ then. Strange, considering $A$ has just been defined as a point and not a position vector, although I understand they're interchangeable for practical purposes.